# How to map product functionality

Tags: interface, information-architecture, app, product-design

At a start of a project, what is the best way to map out all the functionalities of a product? For example, an app?

I've considered a Gantt chart, but I need something more "agile".

What are the best practices? Any advice from professionals? Do you use pen and paper, post-its, or software?

Answer (score 1):

Experiment with a few different methodologies and see what works for you. I'm a whiteboard kind of guy. I always start there making a list of all available functionality, and then try to work out some information architecture by grouping functionality, and labeling what is most important. I think most people from there jump into a number of low fidelity designs. I'm highly visual, so I'll usually start off with a digital medium fidelity design, but that's just me. Try out some different methods and see what works for you and your project!

Answer (score 0):

Try out User Story Mapping. This book greatly teaches how to use this tool: [https://www.amazon.com/User-Story-Mapping-Discover-Product/dp/1491904909](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1491904909) brings a lot of clarity high->low level on what your building and how it brings progress to your users